# Shopify App développement general information

Tags: shopify

im new to shopify, have been working with Wordpress/Prestashop/Magento apps [PHP]. Yet i have to create an app for Shopify, and i need few informations to start in the good direction.

First of all the app need to add the JS to selected Page of the shopify. Example on other platforms i create an admin with listing of all page/ categories of the website, you select them and it add the Js to that spécifique page. 
Question, is that possible with shopify since it's a hosted e-shop?

If it's possible, what to use ?
The shopify Embedded POS package ? [ruby] or start a Php one... im a little bit lost.

Any help appreciated